# Is drag & drop an HTML5 feature?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I could be wrong, but I got the impression that the `Drag & Drop` feature is something associated with HTML5. Is it so?

I took [this](http://programmingusingdotnet.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/aspnet-drag-and-drop-file-uploads-using.html) drag and drop code as an example, but I'm not sure I could find anything HTML5-ish about it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real exact answer for this.  HTML5 is not the same thing as HTML - in that HTML is a simple tag based scripting tool.  HTML5 is too.  But it offers much more.  But it still is not a language exactly.

HTML5 on it's own cannot implement animations.  For that JavaScript and CSS still must be used, at the very least.  But you will often hear someone say "this was done in HTML5."  All that really means is that they combined a bunch of stuff together to acheive the desired effect.  It's never just the one language on its own.

Even the link you specified there very clearly says that it is using an external API to acheive the drag and drop effect.

Comment: Thanks @durbnpoisn, but... I mean, in the link I gave - as you said, they use css and javascript. The only HTML they use is a `div`. So... sorry, I still don't understand what turns it into HTML5. Could you please elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: @Cheshie: HTML5 is simply a name for a set of specifications, including HTML markup, JS APIs and DOM APIs. If you use HTML5 features, then it is HTML5. If you use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype, the browser will assume the *markup* used is HTML5.

Comment: Like I said, HTML5 is a term used to describe how you ENCOMPASS all of those things.  So to say, "all they used is div" is completely missing the point.  Those divs that they used are under control of a boatload of javascript and CSS.  That's how it all works.  Put it all together, and you can call it "HTML5".